# MySQL query to select one table based on values from two different tables.

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've been working on a codeigniter project.

Here are my tables

```
category
cid cname
5   general
6   science
7   math

books
bid bname
12  first
13  second
14  third
15  fourth
16  fifth
17  sixth

dir
id  bid     cid
1   12      5
2   13      6
3   14      7
4   15      6
5   16      5
6   17      5
```

I wanted to display as

```
general 3
science 2
math    1
```

which I have done with the following function code in the model

```
function category_details(){
    $this->db->order_by('cname','asc');
    $query=$this->db->query('Select category.cid,category.cname,count(dir.cid) from dir join category on category.cid=dir.cid join books on dir.bid=books.bid group by category.cname');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Now I want to create a link that will open each category and display the books inside.

Here is how I am trying to do this,

```
View
<a href="<?php echo site_url('category/books/'.$val['cid']);?>">Open</a>

Controller
public function books($cid){

    $data['books']=$this->books_model->get_books($cid);

    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $this->load->view('category_books',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer',$data);

}

Model
function get_books($cid){
 $this->db->where('dir.cid',$cid);
 $query=$this->db->query('select * from books join dir on books.bid=dir.bid join category on dir.cid=category.cid');
 return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

But this is resulting in selecting all the books and not according to the $cid I pass (Although I can see $cid being passed in the url).

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got the result I was after, thanks to @Parvez for the his code. 
I added the "where" condition to it as it is suppose to check for that first and also as I actually wanted to output the books table, I changed books.bname to books.* in the select.
Following is the final Model code that worked accordingly.

```
function get_books($cid){
$this->db->where('dir.cid',$cid)
$this->db->select('dir.*,category.cname,books.*');
$this->db->from('dir'); 
$this->db->join('category', 'category.cid = dir.cid');
$this->db->join('books', 'books.bid = dir.bid');
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
function category_details(){
    $query=$this->db->query('select c.cname, count(d.cid) as total from category as c join dir as d ON c.cid=d.cid group by d.cid order by total DESC');
    return $query->result_array();
    }
```